# Attach JQuery click function to link class

Tags: jquery, class, onclick, sinatra

I'm new to jquery and am a bit confused on how to attach a click function to a link class.

Originally, I attached the onClick function to the link id itself as follows:

```
<div class="summary" style="display:none"></div>
<a id="moreAbout" href="#" >More about #{machine.client_name}</a>

<script> 
  "#moreAbout".onClick(function(event) { 
    event.stop();  
    $$('.summary')[0].slide(); 
    $$('.summary')[0].load("/machine");
  });
</script>
```

and the functionality worked just fine. (Basically, there's a link that you click to show and hide a div)

Now, I need to attach the same function to more than one link. I've tried every tip I can find, and I think there might be an issue with attaching the functionality to a link class.

The most popular solution I've found is as follows:

```
<div class="summary" style="display:none"></div>
<a class="moreAbout" id="alink" "href="#" >More about #{machine.client_name}</a>

<script> 
  $('a.moreAbout').click(function(event) { 
    event.stop();  
    $$('.summary')[0].slide(); 
    $$('.summary')[0].load("/machine");
  });
</script>
```

and I can't seem to make the method attach, let alone make sure the functionality works.

Any insight into why this might not be working?

Answer (score 1):

Using the index with convert that into a `DOM` object

`slide` and `load` are methods available on jQuery Objects.  So you need to convert the `DOM` again into `jQueryObject` to make it work.

Also only a single `$` is sufficient.

`$( $('.summary')[0] )` --> Need to convert to jQuery object again

**Code**

```
$('a.moreAbout').click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();  
    var $summary = $( $('.summary')[0] );
    // The DOM object again converted to jQuery object and stored in 
    // $summary variable. 
    // Now you can apply jQuery method for this object

    $summary.slide(); 
    $summary.load("/machine");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All I had to do was change slide() to slideDown() and it worked perfectly! I appreciate the help

Comment: @KaitlynDornbier.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ //this makes sure the dom is loaded
  $('a.moreAbout').click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent the default action 
    $(this).prev('.summary').slideDown(); //only one $ needed, get the prev parent, 
      //slide is not an event, use slideDown()
    $(this).prev('.summary').load("/machine");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This solution also worked but was a little more confusing for me to understand, just with the $(this).prev annotation. The slideDown() tip was tremendous, though!